# Most efficient method for checking database and adding if not available

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sql-server-2008

The result of my function is always to have the unique ID from the xID column. My 'Name' column is constrained to being unique and the xID is primary and auto-assigned.

Here's my current function:

```
def getid(x):
    cursor.execute('''SELECT xID 
           FROM table
           WHERE Name = '{}';'''
                   .format(x))
    if cursor.rowcount == 0:
        cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO table
                           (Name)
                           VALUES ({0});'''
                       .format(x))
        cursor.commit()
    cursor.execute('''SELECT xID 
           FROM table
           WHERE Name = '{}';'''
                   .format(x))
    return cursor.fetchone()[0]
    cursor.close()
```

This structure is reliable, however, it seems unnecessarily representative. Is there a quicker way of accomplishing this?

Suggested Solution:

```
def getid(x):
    sql = '''INSERT INTO table ([Name])
             SELECT %s
             WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE [Name] = %s)'''

    cursor.execute(sql, (x,x))

    sql = '''SELECT xID 
               FROM table
               WHERE Name = '%s';'''

    cursor.execute( sql, (x,))

    return cursor.fetchone()[0]
    cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the `NOT EXISTS` clause in SQL and be sure to pass in parameters instead of string interpolation with `.format()`.

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO table ([Name])
SELECT %s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE [Name] = %s)'''

cursor.execute(sql, (x,x))
```

Comment: thank you for your input, but this does not work - I can't select a value, it has to be a column.

Comment: Really? See this [rextester demo](http://rextester.com/ZXV86001) showing it is possible to use the `NOT EXISTS` with scalar values without `FROM` in SQL Server. Notice in demo, `Z` is added but not `A`.

Comment: There was an issue with the database connection and this method - it runs in SQL but not my IDE.